# When will native games come to Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, ati, games

Real games that use powerful video cards.

Comment: There are lots of games on linux that need proper graphics cards to run properly with the best graphics.

Comment: That's a "what" question, i'm asking a "when" question. So far what I have seen there are basically no real native 3D intensive games. Hope to see that change.

Comment: Oh. Tell me which question it duplicates because if it's the "What native games are available?" then that is incorrect my question hasn't been answered. I thought that professional Ubuntu staff would be answering my question but instead I got a bunch of people who don't know the answer to my question.

Comment: If you know where to look, you'll find graphically intensive 3D games for linux, so it's a wrong question altogether.

Comment: My question is not "What native games are available?" my question hasn't been answered. I thought a professional Ubuntu staff would be answering my question, this is obviously not professional. It may have been marked as duplicate by vasa1, Takkat, don.joey, Glutanimate, mikewhatever but my question still stands. Have you seen the games on the "What native games are available?" page? Those games are a joke! Let me know if anyone knows the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaming and Linux has been kind of a vicious circle for a long time. Since Linux had (and still has) a small market share, there is little motivation for game developers to port their software, and since there are few games available for Linux, gamers tend to buy Windows anyhow, keeping the market share of Linux small.

Another factor is that game development on Windows is often done using proprietary Windows-Only libraries instead of open standards (I won't go into details, for I'd inevitably start to rant about MS...).

The situation luckily is not that bad any more. For a long time, many independent game developers have been porting or even developing their games for Linux. Most notable is probably the [Humble Indie Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/), which requires each game to have a native Linux version in order to accept it for a bundle (there's one exception). Since you asked about 3D games: The current bundle includes Brütal Legend, which was ported from the Xbox 360.

About a year ago Valve started to port many of their games to Linux, and meanwhile you can get many commercial Valve games and a lot of indie games via [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/). Actually, Valve confirmed that for some games [performance on Linux is superior to Windows](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/faster-zombies/).

Although Steam is using [DRM](https://www.fsf.org/campaigns/drm.html) and therefore one should think twice before supporting it, gamers using Linux should still hope that steam on Linux is a big enough success to make other game developers follow Valves example and port their games for Linux.

A technical side note: While game development on Windows is different from Linux (mainly due to DirectX), the technical differences between MacOS and Linux are much smaller (both use OpenGL, both have OpenAL available, and for input exist libs like SDL that are available for both). So, once a game is ported to either of these 2 operating systems, porting to the other requires a much smaller amount of work than porting from Windows.

Long story short: There are **already** graphically demanding games available for Linux, yet the selection is by far not yet as big as on Windows, but growing.

For many games without a native port, [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) is an acceptable way of running the Windows version, since WINE is not an emulator and can run Windows programs close to native speed (they code is executed natively, yet Windows specific functions have to be translated to their Linux equivalents what creates overhead and slows down execution).